# Understanding Git Hook - post-receive hook

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

I have written simple shell script to throw "success and failure message" and placed it under .git/hooks/ with all proper permissions. I want to call this script as a post-receive. But the script is not working, running the script simply works but as post-receive hook it doesn't work.

Is their something being missed or have i wrongly understood the post-receive hook. Can some one explain client-side and server-side hooks and how to execute them.

I have searched over it but not able to understand.

Comment: I'd suggest showing us a little more, like the script you are using and how you are trying to invoke it.  Also, the [Git Hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) section of Pro Git is helpful, as well as the [githooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) man page.

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to mark it executable? An explicit `sh ./post-receive` will work regardless, but almost nothing else (and not this).

Answer (score 12):

To enable the `post-receive` hook script, put a file in the hooks subdirectory of your .git directory that is same named (without any extension) and make it executable:

```bash
touch GIT_PATH/hooks/post-receive
chmod u+x GIT_PATH/hooks/post-receive
```

> For more info check this doc:  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

### Example

Check this example (*a simple deploy*) `GIT_PATH/hooks/post-receive`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
TARGET="/home/webuser/deploy-folder"
GIT_DIR="/home/webuser/www.git"
BRANCH="master"

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    # only checking out the master (or whatever branch you would like to deploy)
    if [[ $ref = refs/heads/$BRANCH ]];
    then
        echo "Ref $ref received. Deploying ${BRANCH} branch to production..."
        git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f
    else
        echo "Ref $ref received. Doing nothing: only the ${BRANCH} branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
```

> Source: https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa#file-

Comment: I did not understand what is the difference between `TARGET` and `GIT_DIR`...

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be called `post-receive` (no extension, no `post-receive.sh` for instance).

If it is placed (as the OP did) in .git/hooks folder, and made executable, it will be called when you are pushing to that repo (since it is [a server hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks)).
If you were to install it on your own local repo, it would not be called (unless you somehow push to your own repo, which seems unlikely).

For a remote Git hosting server like GitHub, you would need to implement that hook as a **[webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)** (a listener to [GitHub push event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent)).

Comment: How do I install the hook "on server" ? I have just placed it in the .git/hooks folder and made it executable. is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: @Sumit what `git remote -v` returns? What is your server?

Comment: that returns the following:

    origin https://github.<corp>.com/sumit/webhooks.git (fetch)
    origin https://github.<corp>.com/sumit/webhooks.git (push)

where <corp> is my org name.

Comment: @Sumit If this is managed by GitHub (meaning it is not on premise, managed by your company), then you cannot write a post-receive hook, since it is a server-side hook, as described in http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks. You might have a look to https://developer.github.com/webhooks/.

Comment: oh I think I understood. Webhooks is probably what I need. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64759535/automatically-merge-one-branch-into-another-basis-on-some-conditions-using-hook) where I am trying to use git hook to merge branch. I wanted to see if you can help me out.