# Creating a cron to run a post-receive using git but not sure how the paths would look like

Tags: linux, wordpress, git, gitlab, hook

I'm running a cron that involves git as well.  I'm attempting to run a git pull then copy and paste the contents into a specific directory.  Lets say I have the branch;

refs/remote/origin/branch_where_things_are_updated

I want to copy something specific in the branch to
/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/overwrite_this_theme_directory

NOTE: .git is located in the wordpress directory

I'm not sure what the paths are suppose to look like as I'm not really familiar with git, nor its terminology; branch, feature, staging, push, pull, master, origin, etc..

Edit:  git pull says already up to date, thats fine.  But now how to do 'move' the changes that I pulled from the repo to the directory on the server?

Comment: Maybe this thread will help you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106011/understanding-git-hook-post-receive-hook)

Comment: I've seen that thread already.  Its discussing hooks but is there already a pre-made hook to do what I want to do?  I wouldn't even know where to begin to script something like that.